# application failed to start error says autowired to be set to true

Tags: maven, jdbc

[click to see the lines of code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IzTec.png) error message :

Error starting ApplicationContext. To display the conditions report re-run your application with 'debug' enabled.
2022-01-10 11:43:49.180 ERROR 6436 --- [           main] o.s.b.d.LoggingFailureAnalysisReporter   :

---

APPLICATION FAILED TO START

---

Description:

Field productService in com.example.demo1.JdbcTemplateMavenApplication required a bean of type 'com.example.service.ProductService' that could not be found.

The injection point has the following annotations:
- @org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)

Action:

Consider defining a bean of type 'com.example.service.ProductService' in your configuration.

Comment: ProductService wasn't found by Spring

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0):

Add annotation **@Service** to ProductService